# Cleaning messed up my Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I changed some images in `drawable-xxhdpi` folder from jpg to png (by deleting jpg and copying png). When I started Eclipse, the error reported was:

> res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\stripes.png:0: error: Resource entry stripes is
>   already defined. res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\stripes.jpg:0: Originally
>   defined here.

So I look that up and it says I should do Project>Clean, so I do, and now all .java files are are reporting errors on every line where `R.something` is used, for example:

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

reports error `R cannot be resolved to a variable`.

Then I looked this up and the problem is said to be xml errors, but:

1. I didn't touch any of the xml files, I just changed jpgs to pngs
2. none or the xml files have errors reported anywhere

Comment: Just do a close/open project and it should be able to resolve it

Comment: and additionally to @chaitanya , clean the   project

Comment: @Xoce thanks, Usually the eclipse builder works funkily and doing a combination of things seems to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two resources of the same type with the same base name.  You have these two right now:

```
res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\stripes.png
res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\stripes.jpg
```

They have the same base name "stripes" but with different extensions.

When the Android tools build your app, the name of the resource in your R class only contains the base name of your resource, but it will complain if two resources have the same base name.

You just need to give one of them a different base name so they can have two different resources defined.

Comment: Yes, I missed one in one of the drawable folders that I didn't even know was there. Everything's fine now, thanks.